# Regular Expression, getting there but not quite

Tags: regex

Using this code, I can remove all words that start with affirm (lower case "a" at the beginning of the word.  But I can't get other versions, without respect to case, to be removed.  This is despite using "re.I" at the end of my re.sub statement. Any advice?

```
import re
txt='affirmed and the affirmance and AFFIRMED and Affirm case'
wordList = ['affirm\w+', '(ca\w+)']
for word in wordList:
    txt = re.sub(word, '', txt, re.I)
print txt
```

Output:   and the  and AFFIRMED and Affirm

Comment: It is a very well-known issue. Use `re.sub(word, '', txt, flags=re.I)`

Comment: Thank you.  I searched for this answer, but apparently not well enough.  Getting used to the Stack Overflow system.  Really helpful!